# How to rigorously show that $\frac{z^4}{1+z^6}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{z^2}$ for large $|z|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I want to make the integral

$$\int_{C_R}\frac{z^4}{1+z^6}dz$$

disappear, but I just realised I'm having trouble writing down a coherent set of inequalities that would allow me to bound it by $\frac{1}{R^2} \cdot 2 \pi R$. The contour $C_R$ denotes the half circle on the upper complex plane, from $R$ to $-R$. What would be the simplest argument to show that?

Comment: Does $\left|\frac{z^4}{1+z^6}\right| = \frac{1}{|\frac{1}{z^4}+z^2|}\leq\frac{1}{|z^2|-\frac{1}{|z^4|}}$ help?

Comment: You would write $$z^2\frac{z^4}{1+z^6}=\frac{z^6}{1+z^6}$$

Comment: You can just say that $|1+z^6| \ge |z|^6 - 1 \ge |z|^6 - |z|^4 = |z|^4(|z|^2 - 1)$ for $|z| \ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think I like @PedroTamaroff 's argument best in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a coherent set of inequalities that would allow me to bound it by $\frac{1}{R^2}\cdot 2\pi R$

Why $2\pi R$? The length of semicircle is $\pi R$.

Also, I hope you realize that "behaves like $1/z^2$" does not imply that you can bound the function by $1/R^2$. It is true that you can bound it by $C/R^2$, where $C>1$, provided that $R$ is large enough.

One of infinitely many options: when $|z|=R\ge 2$, 
$$
\left| \frac{z^4}{1+z^6}\right| = \frac{R^4}{|1+z^6|} \le \frac{R^4}{|z^6|-|1|}
=\frac{R^4}{R^6-1} \le  \frac{R^4}{R^6/2} = \frac{2}{R^2}
$$